# Date picker not working on appended div using after()

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-after

My html talbe is as follows

```
<table width='1200' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
  <tr>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>
    <li class='demo'><div class='box'>
          <input type='text' id='from-input' maxlength='10'>
          </div>
          <div class='code-box' style='display:none;'>
          <pre class='code prettyprint'>
$('#from-input').multiDatesPicker();
                            </pre>
                        </div>
                    </li></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And my jquery script is as follows.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        var counter =2;
        $("#addButton2").click(function () {

    var newTextBoxDiv2 = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv2' + counter2);

    newTextBoxDiv2.after().html('<table width='1200' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td>Date</td><td><li class='demo'><div class='box'><input type='text' id='from-input'+counter+'' maxlength='10'></div><div class='code-box' style='display:none;'><pre class='code prettyprint'>$('#from-input'+counter+'').multiDatesPicker();</pre></div></li></td></tr></table>');

newTextBoxDiv2.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup2");
    counter++;
    });
```

A button `<input type='button' value='Add' id='addButton2'>` ,When click the button the same copy of the html page is append to a div in the html page. Thera is an input field with id `from-input`  and a jquery function `$('#from-input').multiDatesPicker();` in the html page. the id from-input is changed by attatching the `counter` on each click. The values generated are like from-input2, from-input3, from-input4 and so on. It is the date picker. **The date picker is not working inside the appended tables generated onclick**. any help will be appreciated.Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your code is few issues, Any way try this,

JsFiddle [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/dy5Kk/)

```
$(function() {
   var counter =2;
        $("#addButton2").click(function () {

    var newTextBoxDiv2 = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv2' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv2.after().html("<table width='1200' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td>Date</td><td><li class='demo'><div class='box'><input class='multi' type='text' id='from-input_"+counter+"' maxlength='10'></div><div class='code-box' style='display:none;'>$('#from-input').multiDatesPicker();<pre class='code prettyprint'></pre></div></li></td></tr></table>");

newTextBoxDiv2.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup2");
            $("#from-input_"+counter).multiDatesPicker();
    counter++;

    });

  });
```

Comment: Did you check this solution in IE?

Comment: @jagdish.narkar yes it is working perfectly for my IE.